# Uncaught TypeError: xScale.rangeBand is not a function in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Trying to generate bar chart by following [Vegibit's tutorial](http://vegibit.com/create-a-bar-chart-with-d3-javascript/) in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/499q0un9/).

The `d3.min.js` reference works good.

However when I try to implement [downloaded local copy](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/latest) by using:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>`

The path is [auto generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaWQK.png) by Visual Studio's ASP.NET project tool

```js
    d3BarChart({
      element: '#bar-chart',
      dataSource: [10, 20, 220, 240, 270, 300, 330, 370, 410, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120,
          135, 150, 165, 180, 200],
    });

    function d3BarChart(chartConfig) {

      var dataSource = chartConfig.dataSource;
      var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 50 };

      var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          width = 720 - margin.left - margin.right,
          barWidth = 30,
          barOffset = 10;

      var dynamicColor;

      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(chartConfig.dataSource)])
          .range([0, height])

      var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
          .domain(d3.range(0, chartConfig.dataSource.length))
          .range([0, width])

      var colors = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, chartConfig.dataSource.length])
          .range(['red', 'green'])

      var awesome = d3.select(chartConfig.element).append('svg')
          .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
          .selectAll('rect').data(chartConfig.dataSource)
          .enter().append('rect')
          .style({
            'fill': function (data, i) {
              return colors(i);
            }, 'stroke': '#31708f', 'stroke-width': '5'
          })
          .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
          .attr('x', function (data, i) {
            return xScale(i);
          })
          .attr('height', 0)
          .attr('y', height)
          .on('mouseover', function (data) {
            dynamicColor = this.style.fill;
            d3.select(this)
                .style('fill', 'brown')
          })

          .on('mouseout', function (data) {
            d3.select(this)
                .style('fill', dynamicColor)
          })

      awesome.transition()
          .attr('height', function (data) {
            return yScale(data);
          })
          .attr('y', function (data) {
            return height - yScale(data);
          })
          .delay(function (data, i) {
            return i * 20;
          })
          .duration(2000)
          .ease('elastic')

      var verticalGuideScale = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(chartConfig.dataSource)])
          .range([height, 0])

      var vAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(verticalGuideScale)
          .orient('left')
          .ticks(10)

      var verticalGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
      vAxis(verticalGuide)
      verticalGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
      verticalGuide.selectAll('path')
          .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: "#3c763d" })
      verticalGuide.selectAll('line')
          .style({ stroke: "#3c763d" })

      var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(xScale)
          .orient('bottom')
          .ticks(chartConfig.dataSource.size)

      var horizontalGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
      hAxis(horizontalGuide)
      horizontalGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (height + margin.top) + ')')
      horizontalGuide.selectAll('path')
          .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: "#3c763d" })
      horizontalGuide.selectAll('line')
          .style({ stroke: "#3c763d" });
    }
```

```html
    <div id="bar-chart"></div>
```

it throws the below error:

> Uncaught TypeError: xScale.rangeBand is not a function

Comment: How are you displaying the page? Via a local web server or via files? What browser are you using? Chrome's security model requires all files to be in the same directory if they are accessed directly and not via a web server.

Comment: currently via web server, browser is Chrome

Comment: I'm not sure web servers understand the tilde (~) character.

Comment: The path is [auto generated](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oaWQK.png) by Visual Studio's ASP.NET project tool

Comment: Your downloaded copy is D3 v4. Your code only works with D3 v3.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado If you need to make it work with `D3 v4`, how will you do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is your fiddle, updated to D3 version 4.x: https://jsfiddle.net/jnxh140f/

**Main changes:**

For using objects with `styles` and `attrs` (not `style` and `attr`), you have to reference D3-selection-multi:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```

For the scales:

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(chartdata)])
    .range([0, height])

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(d3.range(0, chartdata.length))
    .range([0, width])
```

For the width:

```
.attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
```

For the axes:

```
var vAxis = d3.axisLeft(verticalGuideScale)
    .ticks(10)

var hAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .ticks(chartdata.size)
```

For the easing:

```
.ease(d3.easeElastic)
```

Plus other small changes (check the code).