# Return values from a map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a script that originated in D3 V3 and I'm trying to rebuild it in V5.

I'll go through the code and then the problem. This is the relevant part of code.

```
var height = 570
var width = 510

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + 160)
    .attr("height", height + 90)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 160 + "," + 90 + ")");

// this has a count for how many are in each group
var grpcnts = {
    met: { '1960': 0, '1970': 0, '2010': 0, label: "First Met", x: 1, y: 1 },
    romantic: { '1960': 0, '1970': 0, '2010': 0, label: "Romantic", x: 2, y: 1 },
    lived: { '1960': 0, '1970': 0, '2010': 0, label: "Live Together", x: 3, y: 1 },
    married: { '1960': 0, '1970': 0, '2010': 0, label: "Married", x: 4, y: 3 },
}

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain([1950, 1970, 1980, 2010])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(d3.keys(grpcnts))
    .range([height, 0]);

var sched_objs = [],
    curr_index = -1;

// Load data 
d3.tsv("timelines.tsv")
    .then(function(data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        var day_array = d.timeline.split(",");
        var activities = [];
        for (var i=0; i < day_array.length; i++) {
            // Duration
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                activities.push({'act': day_array[i-1], 'duration': +day_array[i]});
            }
        }
        sched_objs.push(activities);
    });

    // A node for each person's schedule
    var nodes = sched_objs.map(function(o,i) {
          var act = o[0].act;
          var init_x = x(+data[i].decade) + Math.random();
          var init_y = y('met') + Math.random();
          var col = "#cccccc";
          grpcnts[act][data[i].decade] += 1;

        return {
      act: act,
      radius: maxRadius,
      x: init_x,
      y: init_y,
      decade: data[i].decade,
      color: color(act),
      married: false,
      moves: 0,
      next_move_time: o[0].duration,
      sched: o
        }
      });
    }) // end tsv
```

This is a sample of the dataset.

```
"decade"    "timeline"
1970    "met,4,romantic,14,lived,1,married,-99"
1970    "romantic,2,married,-99"
1970    "met,9,romantic,48,married,-99"
1970    "romantic,20,married,-99"
1970    "met,2,romantic,10,married,-99"
1970    "met,13,romantic,16,married,-99"
```

The problem is that the `x` and `y` fields show up as `NaN`.

[image]

I've added `console.log` statements before the return clause and the init_x and init_y values print out the right numbers.

I've tested the `x()` and `y()` functions with all the valid inputs and they return the right values. I've tested `Math.random()` which appears to work just fine.

None of the other fields show up as `NaN` which leads me to believe that the syntax for returning multiple values is right. I've also tried wrapping `init_x` and `init_y` in Number().

Comment: Hmm, I get x,y values when I run this ([eg](https://jsfiddle.net/n1oLaj2f/2/)) - I have changed a couple things in it to test: I parse the tsv as a csv from the page itself, and I didn't carry through the color scale (as you didn't include it), neither change should affect the outcome. Are you passing `nodes` to a layout out generator or force simulation which might overwrite those properties (seeing as how you also get the right values when logging in the map function, this seems most likely)?

Comment: I do pass it to a `force` variable which could overwrite it. I am hesitant though because I use `console.log` right after that code snippet so I don't know that there would be time for it to get overwritten. The `force` statement is shown here https://pastebin.com/PA0ps1Ub. I also use `var pymChild = new pym.Child();`. Maybe I should try running it with just that section and add other sections one at a time until it breaks.

Comment: A force layout will set x and y properties for each object in the nodes array. I'll take a closer look at the paste bin code tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your code is full of errors, to the point that we cannot make it run without a major refactor.

However, just to answer your current **specific** question (*"where are the NaNs coming from?"*), this is the problem (line 212 in your [pasteBin](https://pastebin.com/PA0ps1Ub)):

```
var k = 0.03 * this.alpha;
```

Since there is no `alpha`, but `alpha()` instead, when you use `k` (which is `undefined`) latter on...

```
o.x += (x(+o.decade) - o.x) * k * damper;
```

... you get that nice and beautiful `NaN`.

I'd like to emphasise again that this change will **not** make your code work, you have a lot of other problems to fix.